# Após edição, editor da pergunta consta como autor na lista

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, perguntas, edição

Notei esse problema na listagem de perguntas (não chequei se o mesmo acontece no Stack Overflow):

[image: Duas perguntas do Stack Overflow em Português]

Ambas as perguntas são de autores diferentes, mas eu fiz pequenas alterações nas mesmas. Por causa disso, quem consta como "autor" da pergunta na página inicial sou eu, e não seus autores originais.

Não acham que a autoria deve permanecer como a do dono original, mesmo após eventuais edições?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, consta que você foi o último que alterou a pergunta. Tanto que, se você abrir a questão verá que o autor ainda é o autor original, mas que essa pergunta foi **editada** por você (nesse caso específico).
Isso acontece também quando alguém responde uma pergunta. O que aparece ali é que o usuário x realizou uma atividade (respondeu, editou ou perguntou) nessa pergunta. Só não vale pra comentários, se eu não estou enganado.

Comment: Isso eu percebi. Na verdade eu penso que aquela informação deveria ser sempre <tempo da criação da pergunta> <autor da pergunta> <pontuação do autor>, e não constar as informações da última pessoa que interagiu com a pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade o que ele faz e foi essa a abordagem pensada pelo designer do sistema é: <tempo da última atividade na pergunta><autor da última atividade><pontuação desse autor>. Isso acontece pra não rolar umas "desenterradas" de tópico, já que o usuário saberá se aquela pergunta está ativa ou não.

Comment: Entendi. Considero a pergunta respondida então :)